# Bootstrap css image center and navbar collapse inline with brand

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the below navbar on my website. All works fine on full screen, however when the screen sizes reduces to max width 992px I am trying to center the logo that is on the screen and move the collapse nav bar to be inline with the logo.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
        <img class="darklogo" href="#page-top" width="30%"  src="img/redlogo.png" />
        <img class="whitelogo" href="#page-top" width="30%" border="0" alt="null" src="img/whitelogo.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger selected" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>




  #mainNav .darklogo {
    display: none;
}


#mainNav .whitelogo {
    display: block;
}



#mainNav.navbar-shrink .darklogo {
    display: block;
}

#mainNav.navbar-shrink .whitelogo {
    display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav .whitelogo {
        display: none;
    }

    #mainNav .darklogo {
       width: 50%;
       display: block;
    }
}
```

I tried adding: align-content = center, this did not work. Also tried justify content = center. This also does not work.

Also the navbar collapse is going underneath the navbar-brand (logo) is it possible to align this on to one line?

[image]

Comment: can you provide working pen or fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xmcfn6r0/4/

Comment: There we go - added a placeholder image. When you reduce the screen size, you will see the navbar collapse underneath the image, i want the image to center and the collapse on the same line as the image

Comment: on media screen try to set img to position:absolute left:50%

Comment: Tried that - it works but when i increase the screen size further, the image starts going below the nav bar into the home page... jsfiddle.net/xmcfn6r0/6

Comment: yeah i see ill try annother solution

Comment: and you have inline style fixed width 30% remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185653/discussion-between-ra19-and-godfather).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/xmcfn6r0/8/

If you change `width` of `.darklogo` also you need to change `left` value of it.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    #mainNav .whitelogo {
        display: none;
    }

    #mainNav .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
    }

    #mainNav .darklogo {
        width: 50%;
        position: relative; 
        left: -25%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has got rid of my logo when i reduce the window size

Comment: @RA19 Can you check again, i have made a small edit.

Comment: For some reason my logo still doesnt appear when the window size is reduced. It seems to vanish.... even with the above code

Comment: Ahh i did it - i need to add display: block; and it shows